# Low latency (<10ms) buffers for USB audio drivers in Windows 10?

Tags: winapi, usb, low-latency, wasapi

I've been working on some WinAPI code to try to get audio latency as low as possible in Windows 10 natively. I eventually found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/low-latency-audio#driver_improvements) documentation which indicates the WASAPI in Windows is the lowest level you can get to, and there are even some improvements in Windows 10 to make the latency even lower. Most notably, support for <10ms audio buffer sizes with newer drivers.

I used the WASAPI but the latency still isn't quite low enough. I'm measuring about 80ms round trip using USB microphone and audio devices. I tested the new drivers mentioned and successfully got lower latency and smaller buffer sizes, but the only drivers mentioned seem to be the "High Definition Audio Device" driver, which I traced to hdaudio.sys. However, typical USB audio devices seem to use "USB Audio Device" drivers, implemented in usbaudio.sys instead I believe, which isn't allowing smaller buffer sizes.

It seems like the changes to allow smaller buffer sizes are relatively minor, but for some reason the stock HD Audio drivers contain these updates but the stock USB Audio drivers do not. What is happening here? Do these updated USB Audio drivers even exist in Windows?

Comment: Specialized software uses ASIO for a reason. If you sure your USB card is capable of low latency IO, there’s a good chance ASIO driver is available for that card.

Comment: I did end up using ASIO. The ASIO4ALL drivers are quite impressive in that they seem to support generic USB audio devices really well. The issue is that ASIO bypasses the Windows audio stack, which means that only one program can access the device at a time. This is a sacrifice I'm willing to make at this point, although I believe I could have accomplished something similar utilizing "exclusive mode" in the WASAPI, and the cool thing about these new drivers I'm asking about is that they apparently work in "shared mode" too, which doesn't require exclusive device control.

Comment: As you seem to have discovered, a low latency like this is not just WASAPI, but [WASAPI Exclusive-Mode Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370844), which enable so called "Pro Audio" mode. Also, ["Both alternatives (exclusive mode and ASIO) have their own limitations. They provide low latency, but they have their own limitations (some of which were described above). As a result, Audio Engine has been modified, in order to lower the latency, while retaining the flexibility."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/low-latency-audio)

Comment: Right, and my original question was about how to utilize some of those flexibility-retaining Audio Engine modifications, which doesn't seem to be possible with current USB drivers.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to operate generic USB audio hardware on Windows at low latency, the KoordASIO driver provides a convenient ASIO-WASAPI bridge, enables either WASAPI Shared or Exclusive mode, and configurable buffer size.

https://github.com/koord-live/KoordASIO

[image]